# jQuery undefined property

Tags: javascript, jquery, joomla

attemping to run a jQuery statement with in Joomla 3.2 and getting an undefined property which references the _basepath line

within the index.php file I have the following code between the head statements

```
JHtml::_('jquery.framework', true, true);
/* a js file created to override the inline style */    
JHtml::_('script',$this->_basePath.'js/override.js', false, true, false, false);
```

within the template folder in js/ I have a js doc called override.js with only the following code

```
jQuery('#sp-feature-wrapper').css(background', '');
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `$this->baseurl` and `$this->template`, like so:

```
JHtml::_('script', $this->baseurl . '/templates/' . $this->template . '/js/override.js');
```

Try also wrapping your jQuery code in document ready as shown below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#sp-feature-wrapper').css('background', '');
});
```

Note that you also missed out a `'` before `background` in your code which I've added in for you.